# ManagedThreadID is not unique?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

My program creates some threads for some tasks.

My code is like this:

```
Dictionary<int, double> threadStates = new Dictionary<int, double>();
for (int i = 0; i < SubNNs.Count(); i++)
{
    Thread tt = new Thread(StartTrainingSubs);
    threadStates.Add(tt.ManagedThreadId, 0);
    tt.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
    tt.Start(i);
}
```

But sometimes, if `SubNNs.Count()` becomes large (10-20), The program throws this exception : "An item with the same key has already been added." at line `threadStates.Add(tt.ManagedThreadId, 0);`

Why I giving this error? Isn't `ManagedThreadId` unique?
If yes, what should I do?

and If no, maybe a thread finishes and another thread starts with same `ManagedThreadId`? Is it possible? how to prevent this problem?

Or there is another problem?

**EDIT : Users said that ManagedThreadId can be reused. So, since in later parts of code, each thread needs to know itself with a unique number, is there any way to add something like a name to thread that every thread can get its unique number?**

Thanks for any advise!

Comment: Yes, thread IDs get recycled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If no, maybe a thread finishes and another thread starts with same ManagedThreadId? Is it possible? how to prevent this problem?

Yes.  Managed thread IDs can be reused.  They are not a good choice for a dictionary state key.

Instead of using the thread ID to track state, you should consider using some other unique value.  In your case, "i" is unique per loop - why not use it as your key?

Comment: Thanks. "i" is unique, that's right. but in another part of code, every thread needs to know itself, every thread knows its ManagedThreadId, but not about "i".

Comment: Can I set something like a name to every thread? So, every thread can identify itself?

Comment: @Mahdi What do you need the thread ID for?  You can pass the information to a thread's start - you're doing that now (`tt.Start(i);`)  Just pass the state you require.  If you need a unique identifier, pass one into the ParameterizedThreadStart routine right up front.

Comment: Each thread calls another function in a class, and the events of every class should have a unique number to identify itself. So, seems that I should add a ID variable into that class and fill it with "i". So, every thread can identify itself. Right?

Comment: I have used ManagedThreadId before in a hash table as the key lookup.  However, before calling .Add(), make sure you call .Exists(), and reuse the entry if it already exists.  That way you will not attempt to add a thread id that was reused.